# How can I tag a snapshot based on an array containing snapshot id

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, sdk

I am trying to tag a sets of snapshots based on some check. I am putting all snapshot_ids in an Array. Now I want to tag them with a tag based on another condition.

Like I am using below:

```
client=Aws::EC2::Client.new(region: 'ap-southeast-2', retry_limit: 15))
resp=client.describe_snapshots({owner_ids['*****']})

resp.snapshots.each do |varEach|
            counter+=1
if (SOME CHECKS)

< HERE I WANT TO TAG THEM>

end

end
```

Could you kindly help me in achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the general purpose [create_tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html#create_tags-instance_method) method to tag them all at the same time, for example:

```
resp = client.create_tags({
  resources: [
    "snap-03a123b99e88a123f",
    "snap-03a444b55e66a777f",
  ], 
  tags: [
    {
      key: "Stack", 
      value: "production", 
    }, 
    {
      key: "Owner", 
      value: "abhiks", 
    }, 
  ], 
})
```

Comment: client.create_tags({
    dry_run: false,
    resources: [
        "snap-xxxxxxxxxx",
    ],
    tags: [
        { 
            key: "my_key", 
            value: "this-value",
        },],
        })

This worked for me,,,

I hope passing an array would also work.. 

```

 resources:AnArray,
    tags: [

```